# how to configure image domain in next.config.js file to accept blob images?

Tags: next.js, localhost, blob, next-images

I'm facing 'Error: Invalid src prop (blob:http://localhost:3000/76946c41-4864-4fe7-9b95-030d4a9b8dd5) on `next/image`, hostname "" is not configured under images in your `next. config.js`'. In the documentation of the NextJS informs the way to add the domain of the image in the settings, but I am not able to configure it for this specific type of image.
already tried putting

```
images: {
    domains: ["localhost"],
  }
images: {
    domains: ["localhost:3000"],
  }
images: {
    domains: ["blob:localhost"],
  }
```

but without resolution

Comment: Blob URLs are currently [not supported](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/19291) by `next/image`.

Comment: I ended up using the html img tag